# Pivot multiple email addresses to columns

Tags: case, sql-server-2017

I need to pivot the email table so that the different email addresses are displayed in different columns. The data is relatively simple. I get the following error messages for the code below which is perplexing. Line 6, Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.  Line 14, Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'. Thank you for all your help in advanced! I am a relative newbie :)

[image: Original Table]

I need the emails to be in different columns
[image: DesiredTable]

```
``  
      SELECT Emails.entity_FK,
             CASE WHEN emails.MyDefault = 1 THEN emails.EmailAddress END AS EmailPrimary,
             CASE WHEN em.RowNum = 1 THEN em.EmailAddress END AS Email_2,
             CASE WHEN em.RowNum = 2 THEN em.EmailAddress END AS Email_3,
             CASE WHEN em.RowNum = 3 THEN em.EmailAddress END AS Email_4,

       FROM Emails
            LEFT JOIN
            (
            SELECT Entity_FK, EmailAddress,  
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Entity_FK ORDER BY Email_PK) 
               as RowNum
            FROM emails
            WHERE MyDefault = 0 AND EntityTypeCode_FK = 126 
            )  AS em
             emails.Entity_FK = em.Entity_FK
            WHERE emails.EntityTypeCode_FK = 126
    ``
```

Comment: you have an extra `comma` after `Email_4` just before the `FROM`

Comment: Thank you Squirrel! For anyone trying to follow this, I also needed MAX before the various cases

Comment: **Entity_FK** value for rows 4 and 5 is actually 1 or is it a typo and value should be 2?

Comment: please add your data as txt format for create test case in my db and write true query